# Android Google Play Services API for GPS only?

Tags: android, google-maps

this might seem like a very stupid question to you, but I haven't found any answer to it yet.

In Android, there are two possibilities of making the application location aware. a) with the Android Location API or b) with the `Google Play Services API`. It is recommended to use the `Google Play Services API` since it's less battery draining and provides more accuracy.

But what if I only wanted to use GPS? No additional accuracy by combining some mobile data etc. Just plain GPS without having any internet connection. Is it still preferable to use the `Google Play Services API`? Also, does it require internet connection at some point? The `onConnect()` method is supposed to be called when a connection to the `GoogleApiClient`  is established. Does that mean that a connection to a Google Server is needed or only that the locally saved Google Play Services (on the device) is connected to?

Comment: I think you can still use the `GoogleApiClient` to get position, because it avoid `null point error`. For the instruction, check [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android), and for the source code check my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/getLastLocationUsingGPS-android).